# Prove $n = (1 + a_n)^n ≥ n(n − 1)a_n^2 /2]$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Show that $n^{1/n} → 1$. [Hint: let $a_n := n^{1/n} − 1$. Then $n = (1 + a_n)^n ≥ n(n − 1)a_n^2 /2]$.

I know how to prove this in using the hint and the squeeze theorem, but how is it possible to prove $n = (1 + a_n)^n ≥ n(n − 1)a_n^2 /2]$? I thought using a taylor series, but I can't use it.

Answer (score 2):

By Binomial Theorem:

$$(1+a_n)^n = \sum_{k=0}^n \binom nk a_n^k \ge \binom n 2 a_n^2 = n(n-1)a_n^2/2$$